# Cannot find module '@angular/core' after angular-cli update

Tags: angularjs, angular

My application was working just well. Until I wanted to use angular-in-memory-web-api which returned undefined.

I thought updating my angular-cli to latest may work. But now I get the 'Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

Here are the steps I used for updating:

Updating angular-cli

To update angular-cli to a new version, you must update both the global package and your project's local package.

Global package:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
Local project package:

rm -rf node_modules dist tmp
npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest
ng init
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you deleted the node_modules folder. Try running "npm install" again.